# Trying to set up a simple swapping system to swap two game pieces using a button press

Tags: unity, c#

I am trying to set up a system that will move two objects. This is a puzzle game with a cursor to visualize where the player is. I need to get the position of the cursor's left and right half, send that to a function that will then switch the two blocks when a key is pressed.

I have code that will move the cursor around but cannot figure out how to swap two blocks based on the position of the cursor.

I do not know if the code that is currently attached to the cursor will be of any help, but I can provide if necessary.

I am more or less looking for a general solution that I could apply to swapping two blocks.

I do not know if I need to be sending the positions of the cursor to the swap function in order to swap. How would I connect this to the tiles themselves? The code below is located in the board classv2 class. I am not very good with Unity as of yet. Any additional help would be appreciated.

```
 void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetButtonUp("Swap"))
        {
            swapTiles(cursorLeft.transform.position.x, cursorRight.transform.position.x);
        }
    }

void swapTiles(float x1, float x2)
{


}
```

Game pieces are created and have an x and y number associated with a game board I created.

The Game pieces have a move routine. I can't seem to get the pieces to actually swap.

```
public void Move(int destX, int destY, float timeToMove)
{
    if (!m_isMoving)
    {
        StartCoroutine(MoveRoutine(new Vector3(destX, destY, 0), timeToMove));
    }  
}

//Moves the piece.
IEnumerator MoveRoutine(Vector3 destination, float timeToMove)
{
    Vector3 startPosition = transform.position;

    bool reachedDestination = false;

    float elapsedTime = 0f;

    m_isMoving = true;

    while (!reachedDestination)
    {
        //if we are close enough to destination
        if (Vector3.Distance(transform.position, destination) < 0.01f)
        {
            reachedDestination = true;

            if(m_board != null)
            {
                m_board.PlaceGamePiece(this, (int)destination.x, (int)destination.y);
            }
            break;
        }

        //track the total running time
        elapsedTime += Time.deltaTime;

        //calculate the lerp value
        float t = Mathf.Clamp(elapsedTime / timeToMove,0f,1f);

        switch (interpolation)
        {
            case InterpType.Linear:
                break;
            case InterpType.EaseOut:
                Mathf.Sin(t * Mathf.PI * 0.5f);
                break;
            case InterpType.EaseIn:
                t = 1 - Mathf.Cos(t * Mathf.PI * 0.5f);
                break;
            case InterpType.SmoothStep:
                t = t * t * (3 - 2 * t);
                break;
            case InterpType.SmootherStep:
                t = t * t * t * (t * (t * 6 - 15) + 10);
                break;
        }

        //move the game piece
        transform.position = Vector3.Lerp(startPosition, destination, t);

        //wait until next frame
        yield return null;
    }
    m_isMoving = false;
}
```

[image: Cursor is in the Bottom Left.]

Comment: The first problem you would need to solve is to translate cursor coordinates to board coordinates. The second problem would then be to obtain pieces by their board coordinates. How easy or hard that's going to be and what the best approach would be depends on how you implemented your game grid. And there is no "normal" way to do that.

Comment: And figure out what you mean by left and right. I mean you hover over one tile. Should it swap with the left or the right?

Comment: The tiles would overall swap with each other. It would not matter if the left is swapping or the right. Is there some example code that translates coordinates of a different object to a different objects coordinates?